# What are the new language features in scala 2.11.x compared to 2.10?

Tags: scala

My team uses libraries which depends on scala 2.10.

And we would like to migrate our code-base to scala 2.11.x.

We've read the [overview of scala 2.11](http://docs.scala-lang.org/scala/2.11/). It focuses on new features in REPL which is not something we are looking after.

In particular,

- What are the syntax difference between 2.10 and 2.11.x?
- Which part of code that we need to rewrite because of syntax change?
- What libraries currently only support 2.10 that by using 2.11.x I forfeit the ability to use those libraries? (e.g. spark)

Thanks

Comment: may help: http://scala-lang.org/news/2.11.1

Comment: @dk14 Thanks for the reminder. Would you provide some insight about library compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, the only syntax change is the removal of octal literals which however had been deprecated anyway.